# nginx redirect / rewrite issue on specific rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a nginx situation that I would need a bit of help with.

The story:

- There once was an website, let's call it website.com, that had virtual subdomains created in it. Every URL like **subdomain**.website.com was created on the fly (there were **subdomain**.website.com, **anothersubdomain**.website.com, **someothersubdomain**.website.com and so on)
- Each created subdomain had an internal structure, like **subdomain**.website.com/*some/internal/structure/* or **subdomain**.website.com/*some-file.html*
- Now, the owner wants to permanently move all the subdomains inside the main website, like this website.com/sub-**subdomain**/ or website.com/sub-**subdomain**/*some/internal/structure* or website.com/sub-**subdomain**/*some-file.html*

What I have now are the rules for catching the subdomains and redirect them inside the main website, as follows:

```
if ($http_host !~ "^www.website.com"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}

if ($http_host ~ "([^.]+).website.com"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    set $bref_1 $1;
}

if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite  ^/(.*)  http://www.website.com/sub-$bref_1/ permanent;
}
```

The problem is that if I have an URL like **subdomain**.website.com/*some/internal/structure/* or **subdomain**.website.com/*some-file.html* all I get with the above code snippet is this www.website.com/sub-**subdomain**/ and I'm losing the rest of the subdomain structure (the "*some/internal/structure/*" or the "*some-file.html*" parts - without the quotes, of course)

How should I alter the code snippet above so that I'll preserve tho lost parts mentioned above?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the meantime I've come up with this solution:

I've canceled the code snippet above and replaced with this one

```
if ($http_host ~ "([^.]+).website.com") {
    set $bref_1 $1;
}

if ($bref_1 != "www") {
    return 301 http://www.website.com/sub-$bref_1$request_uri;
}
```